# How can I install GNU Parallel alongside Moreutils?

Tags: macos, homebrew, gnu-parallel

Homebrew has a formula for [`moreutils`](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/moreutils.rb) and [GNU `parallel`](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/parallel.rb).

GNU Parallel conflicts with Moreutils since it also has a binary called `parallel`, which is just less useful. However I'd still like to install both formulae at the same time. How can I do that?

Ideally, I'd install GNU Parallel as `gparallel` – akin to the naming of the Coreutils binaries – to avoid these conflicts, but I don't see a way to specify that in the formula itself, since `prefix` is just the Homebrew prefix.

```
def install                                                                                                                               
    system "./configure", "--prefix=#{prefix}"                                                                                              
    system "make install"                                                                                                                   
end
```

Any way to get the best of both worlds?

Comment: Are you aware that certain features of GNU Parallel depends on the program being called `parallel`?

Comment: No, I wasn't. Could you explain what these are? (Also, why is there a configuration option that lets you change this so easily?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to install a third-party version of the formula:

```
brew install slhck/moreutils/moreutils --without-parallel
```

Then:

```
brew install parallel
```

Comment: _brew_ still complained `Error: Cannot install parallel because conflicting formulae are installed`. The second command should be `brew install parallel --force`.

Comment: This no longer works in OSX High Sierra, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1289636/running-brew-install-moreutils-without-parallels-fails)

Answer (score 11):

In homebrew 2.0 [options have been removed](https://brew.sh/2019/02/02/homebrew-2.0.0/)

The way to get GNU parallels working now is

```
brew unlink moreutils
brew install parallel
brew link --overwrite moreutils
brew unlink parallel
brew link --overwrite parallel
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use all of the tools in `moreutils`, or just `sponge`, which is the most general purpose one? If so, you can get `sponge` in a brew package by itself:

```
brew uninstall moreutils
brew install sponge
```

`sponge` by itself has no conflicts with another package, so you should be able to use that alongside `parallel`.