# Running “brew install moreutils --without-parallels” fails

Tags: homebrew, macos-highsierra

I’ve recently upgraded to macOS High Sierra. I’ve updated and upgraded homebrew. I’ve done:

```
brew install parallel
```

And now I need to:

```
brew install moreutils --without-parallel
```

This fails. Looking at:

```
$HOME/Library/Logs/Homebrew/moreutils/05.make
```

I can see that this is related to `docbook-xsl`:

```
xsltproc --param man.authors.section.enabled 0 /usr/local/opt/docbook-xsl/docbook-xsl/manpages/docbook.xsl ifdata.docbook
error : Operation in progress
http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.4/dbpoolx.mod:3729: warning: failed to load external entity "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.4/calstblx.dtd"
%tablemodel;
            ^
Entity: line 1:
 %tablemodel;
             ^
error : Operation in progress
error : http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.4/docbookx.dtd:155: warning: Operation in progress
failed to load external entity "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.4/dbhierx.mod"
http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.4/dbpoolx.mod:3729: warning: failed to load external entity "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.4/calstblx.dtd"
%tablemodel;
            ^
Entity: line 1:
 %tablemodel;
             ^
%dbhier;
        ^
Entity: line 1:
 %dbhier;
         ^
error : Operation in progress
http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.4/docbookx.dtd:155: warning: failed to load external entity "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.4/dbhierx.mod"
%dbhier;
        ^
Entity: line 1:
 %dbhier;

...
```

Comment: This is not expected. I'd recommend creating a bug report here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues (make sure you fill out the issue template)

Comment: @slhck I submitted the but report with Homebrew/homebrew-core over [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/23441)

Comment: As mentioned, please fill out the issue template there, too. (“we will close your issue without comment if you delete, do not read or do not fill out the issue checklist”)

Comment: @slhck it seems to be working this morning.

Answer (score 1):

This can be closed as it seems the issue was fixed overnight.

```
$ brew install parallel
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/parallel-20180122.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/deant/Library/Caches/Homebrew/parallel-20180122.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring parallel-20180122.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/parallel/20180122: 65 files, 3.2MB
$ brew install moreutils --without-parallel
==> Cloning https://git.joeyh.name/git/moreutils.git
Updating /Users/deant/Library/Caches/Homebrew/moreutils--git
==> Checking out tag 0.62
==> Downloading https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/N/NE/NEILB/Time-Duration-1.20.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/deant/Library/Caches/Homebrew/moreutils--Time::Duration-1.20.tar.gz
==> perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=/usr/local/Cellar/moreutils/0.62/libexec --skipdeps
==> make install
==> Downloading https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/T/TO/TODDR/IPC-Run-0.94.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/deant/Library/Caches/Homebrew/moreutils--IPC::Run-0.94.tar.gz
==> perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=/usr/local/Cellar/moreutils/0.62/libexec
==> make install
==> make all
==> make check
==> make install PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/moreutils/0.62
  /usr/local/Cellar/moreutils/0.62: 65 files, 558.2KB, built in 38 seconds
```

Comment: `brew install moreutils --without-parallel` yields `Error: invalid option: --without-parallel` for me.

Answer (score 1):

In homebrew 2.0 [options have been removed](https://brew.sh/2019/02/02/homebrew-2.0.0/)

> Homebrew does not have any formulae with options in Homebrew/homebrew-core. Options will still be supported and encouraged by third-party taps

Installing GNU parallels is answered in https://superuser.com/a/1537888/352308